# How to remove some specific autocomplete in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2, sublimetext, code-snippets

I have Sublime Text 2 installed with the Emmet package (Windows 7 64bits).

When I type "**wid**", I want the auto-complete first suggestion to be "**width**".
Problem is, right now it suggests "**widows**" which is very rarely used.

How can I modify the order of suggestions, or maybe even better, remove the "widows" auto-complete suggestion altogether?

Answer (score 12):

**Referencing:** https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/snippets.json

**ST3: Emmet: Settings - User**

```
{
    "disable_completions": false,

    // This solution works to override annoying autocompletions from emmet.
    // I could do without seeing "widows" ever again, but just in case I added it back so that "widows" won't autocorrect to "width"

    "snippets": {
        "css": {
            "filters": "css",
            "profile": "css",
            "snippets": {
                "wid": "width:|;",
                "widows": "widows:|;"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT: The solution of deleting files did not work for me.  Hitting tab after typing in "width" still autocompleted to "widows: ;" on my machine.***

Answer (score 3):

- sublime will slowly 'learn' what you want most

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/auto_complete.html

> "By default, the selected item in the completion popup will be committed when enter is pressed. This can create ambiguity between committing the completion, and inserting a newline. By setting the auto_complete_commit_on_tab setting to true, enter will insert a newline, and tab will commit the current completion. There are other benefits, too: because Sublime Text knows there is no ambiguity, it will show a more curated list of completions, with the one you want more likely to be in first place.
>
> Enabling Commit on Tab is recommended, but it will take a short time to get used to."

- if you want to delete a specific snippet:

go to 'preferneces->browse packages'
there should be a 'emmet css snippets' folder there.
inside that folders are all of the snippets available, as invividual files named:
'shortcut'.sublime-snippet (wid.sublime-snippet stands for 'width')

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is just type "w" and TAB. This is the abreviattion for "width: ;" according to [Emmet Cheat Sheet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem,

try to open `Preferences > Browse For Package`

on window open `CSS` folder and edit `css_completions.py` file, drag file to sublime and find `widows`, remove code on the line, I already try and it's work on mu sublime.

Comment: these _completions.py file seem to govern much of this behavior.